# How to setup an account in IBM mainframes programatically

Tags: cobol, mainframe, rexx

I need to create a user account in IBM mainframes(Z-os,os390, i-series) through a program. 
Is there any libraries which are built-in in Mainframe OS to be used by the programming languages such as cobol.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Zos and os390 are the same but i-series is a different architecture

Comment: Are you looking for callable routines, say something like "create_user(uidstring)" (not a real function)? Your answer to this will help us understand

Comment: I am doing user provisioning application which creates user in all enterprise systems. Hence I would like to create a user and reset users password by any possible chance.

Comment: It depends on what security product are you using? `RACF` or `TopSecret`? And you need an existing TSO id to create a new TSO id.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that COBOL is the correct language for what I think you are trying to accomplish. To create user accounts programmatically, you would need to create an account in TSO, create and assign a default PDS (or have a startup routine that does that), assign security and rights via **RACF** or **TopSecret**, and there maybe a number of other tables and files that would require updating with the new user info.

Further, most shops when creating a new TSO id also create the login credentials in CICS, DB2, QMF, etc. But, I digress. Anyway, with the various steps needed, your best bet would be something like **REXX** to try to automate as much as possible. You would likely have to research each of steps to see if in fact they are scriptable using REXX.